# »Top-5-« oder »Top-5«?

Tags: spelling, hyphen

Gestern ergab sich eine Diskussion zwischen mir (Ausländer) und einem Muttersprachler, ob es nun:

> (1) die Top 5 Städte
>
> (2) die Top-5 Städte

oder

> (3) die Top-5-Städte

heißen soll, wenn *die fünf größten / schönsten* (was auch immer) *Städte* gemeint sind. Ich vertrat durch die Analogie zu *die fünf X-sten* die Schreibweise (1) oder (2), mein Kollege allerdings die (3). Seinen Standpunkt richtig begründen konnte aber keiner von uns. Was sagt ihr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nichts davon. *Top 5* ist ein Anglizismus, der sich im Gegensatz zu anderen Anglizismen noch nicht den deutschen Grammatikregeln unterworfen hat. Demnach wäre eine der beiden Formulierungen:

> Die fünf besten Städte.
>
> Die besten fünf Städte.

---

Das ist aber nicht die Antwort, die du suchst, denn natürlich findet der Ausdruck *top 5* immer mehr Verwendung im Deutschen; und auch wenn die in der Frage gestellte Konstruktion stilistisch fragwürdig ist, ist sie doch nicht semantisch falsch.

*Top 5* an sich steht üblicherweise ohne Bindestrich, denn *top* wird in der Regel als englisches Adjektiv, *5* aber oft als Ziffer *fünf* ausgesprochen. Wenn jetzt ein Substantiv dahintergestellt wird, ergeben sich folgende Möglichkeiten:

1. Es wird als reguläre Aneinanderreihung von Adjektiv und Substantiv (mit Zahlwort) verstanden, also:

   > Die top 5 Städte.
2. Es wird als Zusammenfügung des Ausdrucks *Top 5* mit dem Substantiv *Stadt* verstanden, also:

   > Die Top-5-Städte.

Zu guter Letzt kann man allerdings auch *top 5* als feststehenden Ausdruck verstehen. Falls man das tut, muss man ihn mit Bindestrich schreiben:

> Die top-5 Städte.

Das würde ich vor Allem verwenden, wenn ich die *5* gerne englisch als *five* ausgesprochen sähe.

Je nach Intention des Schreibers sind also alle drei Varianten möglich. Bevorzugen unter diesen würde ich die bindestrichfreie Variante, denn in meinem Verständnis sind es Adjektiv und Substantiv (mit Zahlwort dazwischen).

Beachte übrigens die Großschreibung: Nur dort, wo *top* zum Substantiv dazugehört, also wo vollständig durchgekoppelt wird, ist Großschreibung angebracht.

Comment: Ich bin eigentlich ein großer Verfechter der Durchkoppelung mit Bindestrich, aber Top-5-Städte impliziert __gefühlt__ eine feste Gruppe, und nicht einfach die besten fünf einer bestimmten Rangliste, die sich von Liste zu Liste unterscheiden. Ich würde also am ehesten zu 1. tendieren, da es sich im Grunde um "die besten fünf Städte" handelt, also grammatisch völlig korrekt, nur "besten" durch "top" (kleingeschrieben weil Adjektiv) und "fünf" durch "5" (üb)ersetzt.

Comment: @Raketenolli Das verleitet mich dazu, den Ausdruck mit umgestellten Attributen oben dazuzuschreiben. ;)

Comment: Sind die besten fünf Städte nicht was anderes als die fünf besten Städte? Ähnlich wie es vor kurzem hier mit dem bösen großen, äh, ich meine großen bösen Wolf war. Imho einzig richtig sind die "fünf besten Städte".

Comment: @Em1 Durchaus möglich. Der Unterschied zum bösen, großen Wolf liegt darin, dass *fünf* ein Zahlwort und kein Adjektiv ist, für das andere Regeln gelten. Ursprünglich habe ich ja auch nur die *fünf besten* stehengehabt, weil das meinem Sprachgefühl besser entsprochen hat.

Comment: Gute Frage. Man könnte meinen, dass die fünf besten Städte grundsätzlich die fünf besten Städte sind (weil "beste Städte") -- wie auch immer man zu diesem Schluss gekommen ist (bei "die fünf schnellsten 100-m-Läufer" ist es deutlich offensichtlicher) -- wohingegen sich die "top 5" m. W. immer auf eine Rangliste beziehen, wodurch die "besten fünf" weiter qualifiziert werden, da geht es also um die "besten fünf Städte [im Bereich Sehenswürdigkeiten, Umweltschutz, ...]".

Comment: Die *Top 5* einer Rangliste (wie auch immer man das nun schreibt) sind aber nicht zwangsläufig die *besten*; da können auch andere Adjektive angebracht sein. In einer Liste der verbrechensreichsten Großstädte würde ich z.B. unter den "Top 5" andere verstehen als unter den "besten" (sofern man Letzteres überhaupt sagen würde).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das ist richtig; gegebenenfalls muss das *beste*-Adjektiv der Situation angepasst werden.

Comment: @Jan: Das sorgt für den interessanten Umstand, dass *Top 5* in der Tat die passendste Formulierung zu sein scheint, wenn man sich auf eine beliebige Rangfolge beziehen möchte (wenn an der Stelle, an der man sich auf die "Top 5" bezieht, also noch nicht klar ist, ob *beste* oder ein anderes Adjektiv am passendsten ist). Sofern es nicht noch eine andere, handliche (kürzer als *die ersten 5 Plätze in der Rangfolge belegenden ...*) Formulierung gibt natürlich.